# manually restarting only works

Tags: python, bash, shell, websocket, bots

My until do script is not restarting when websocket server gets dropped/closed. I have to manually type python myscript.py for it to connect again. It wont restart on its own.

```
until myscript; do
    echo "'myscript' crashed with exit code $?. Restarting..." >&2
    sleep 2
done
```

I want to my script be able to restart on its own any time it crashes or connection gets closed please.

Comment: Does the error message ever get printed?

Comment: Does mybot.py exit with an error status (i.e. not zero) when it gets gets dropped/closed?

Comment: Do not post a different question to update. Make edits to this one.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect @Gordon is on the right track. Perhaps

```bash
while { myscript; rc=$?; true; }; do
    echo "'myscript' crashed with exit code $rc. Restarting..." >&2
    sleep 2
done`
```